# Clone an object that contains DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, clone

I'm trying to create a html5 video help for a project. I've setup a basic video object, shown below. I'm adding and removing these videos to the page numerous times so I have setup a VideoPool array containing these objects.

I want to be able to clone a video from the pool and add it to the page. This should allow me to have multiple instances of the same video on the page?

```
$.extend( true, {}, <Video from pool> )
```

I've tried using jquery extend, but it doesn't seem to clone the videos dom element ( this.el ) correctly.

Does anyone know if this can be done like this, or is there another method? Thanks

```
var Video = (function(){

    function Video( src ){
        this.el = document.createElement('video');
        this.$el = $( _this.el );
        this.el.src = src;
        this.el.controls = false;
        this.el.loop = true;
        this.el.preload = true;
    }

    Video.prototype.play = function() { }

    Video.prototype.stop = function() { }

    ...

    return Video;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The cloneNode() method seems like what you're looking for.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode